# Cases environment doesn't work

Tags: equations, errors, compiling, cases, compilation-error

I'm trying to write this:

```
$$\begin{cases}
    2a - b = 3 \\
    a + 2b = 4 \\
    3c - d = 1 + i \\
    c - 3d = -i
    \end{cases} \Longrightarrow 
    \begin{cases}
    2a - b = 3 \\
    a = 4 - 2b \\
    3c - d = 1 + i \\
    c = -i + 3d
    \end{cases} \Longrightarrow
    \begin{cases}
    2(4 - 2b) - b = 3 \\
    a = 4 - 2b \\
    3(-i + 3d) - d = 1 + i \\
    c = -i + 3d
    \end{cases} \Longrightarrow $$
```

But, I don't know what is wrong.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside,brazil]{icmc}

\usepackage{amsmath}         
\usepackage{color}    
\usepackage{xcolor}        
\usepackage{colortbl}        
\usepackage[top=25mm,bottom=25mm,left=25mm,right=20mm]{geometry} %coloca o tamanho das margens              
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}             
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}            
\usepackage{setspace} %espacamento entre linhas               
\usepackage{natbib} %referencias com numera\c{c}\~{a}o              
%\usepackage[brazil]{babel}                   
\usepackage[portuges]{babel}                       
%\let\cite=\citep                 
\usepackage{url}                      
\usepackage{fancybox}                       
\usepackage{indentfirst} %indenta a primeira linha               
\usepackage{times}       %utiliza a fonte Times New Roman                  
\usepackage{graphicx} %pacote para incluir imagens                  
\usepackage{titlesec} %para os gr\'{a}ficos dos cap\'{\i}tulos            
\usepackage{textfit}                   
\usepackage{fancyhdr} % Para colocar cabe\c{c}alho nas p\'{a}ginas       
\usepackage{lettrine} % Para fazer letras capitulares         
\usepackage{hyperref}           
\usepackage{amsthm}          
\usepackage{amssymb}          
\usepackage{amsfonts}            
\usepackage{bezier}            
\usepackage{amstext}         
\usepackage{graphicx}          
\usepackage{subfigure}      
\usepackage{amscd}           
\usepackage{amsxtra}            
\usepackage{array}              
\usepackage{float}           
\usepackage{maple2e}           
\usepackage{pdfpages}            
\usepackage{mathtools}        

\begin{equation*}
            \begin{pmatrix}
            i & 1 \\
            -1 & i
            \end{pmatrix} \cdot \begin{pmatrix*}
            x \\ y
            \end{pmatrix*} = \begin{pmatrix}
            0 \\ 0
            \end{pmatrix} \Leftrightarrow  \begin{cases}
            i x + y = 0 \\
            -x + i y = 0
            \end{cases} \Leftrightarrow \begin{cases}
            y = -ix \\
            0 = 0
            \end{cases}.
            \end{equation*}
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TEX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/82917) There is nothing wrong in the code you show (except `$$` which shouldn't be used in LaTeX), so whatever is happening is related to some code you are not showing. Please provide a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/82917) which reproduces the issue, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. And no screenshots: they are difficult to copy/paste in an editor.

Comment: Did you remember to load the `amsmath` package?

Comment: @Mico I see the `amsmath` package in the first screenshot. This code compiles without error just using that one package, so my guess is, that one of the other packages causes this behaviour.

Comment: Can you provide an MWE, which displays this error?

Comment: Where does the `icmc` class come from, it is not a wellknown class.

Comment: Load on MikTex?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm new here. I'll put the code in the question.

Comment: You have posted a lot of code but most of it unrelated to the problem, and we can not use it as it uses a class `icmc` not in texlive and it is incomplete, no `\end{document}` you should be able to make an example just using `article` class and just `mathtools`

Comment: I put all the code in because I don't know where the problem is. I didn't create this model, my teacher gave it to me and I always used it without any problem. However, today this error with the cases environment started to appear. Can you explain to me how to set a good example?

Comment: I took the core part of your example and added it to the end, but it appears to work, if that is not what you are seeing edit it (adding code back from your original document) so it shows the problem that you see.

Comment: @SabrinaMarques first thing is try replacing `icmc` on the first line by `article` if that makes the error go away then the problem is in that file which is probably a local file just at your institution?

Comment: Thank you very much! I managed to find out where the problem is. I redid the question, is it better to delete it?